# Importing a component into Vue and then passing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a component in my Nuxt project.

components/Boxes.vue:

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
        <b-col v-for="box in boxes" v-bind:key="box">
          <b-card 
          :title="box.title"
          class="text-center mt-5">
            <p class="card-text">
              {{ box.text }}
            </p>
            <b-button
            variant="danger"
            >Find out more</b-button>
          </b-card>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Boxes",
  data() {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then I want to import it into pages/index.vue

```
<template>
<div id="home">
  <b-container>
    <b-carousel 
      id="carousel1"
      class="mt-2"
      style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
      controls
      indicators
      background="#ababab"
      :interval="4000"
      img-width="1024"
      img-height="480"
      v-model="slide"
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
    >
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="./slides/slide1.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="./slides/slide2.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="./slides/slide3.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="./slides/slide4.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
  </b-container>
  <Boxes/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Boxes from '@/components/Boxes.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Boxes
  },
  data () {
    return {
      slide: 0,
      sliding: null,
      boxes: [
        {
          title: 'Fire Stopping',
          text: 'How does it work?'
        },
        {
          title: 'Our Services',
          text: 'Full range of firestopping'
        },
        {
          title: 'Bid Request',
          text: 'Inexpensive peace of mind'
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSlideStart (slide) {
      this.sliding = true
    },
    onSlideEnd (slide) {
      this.sliding = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It's acting as if I have not imported it when I make the attempt to load it on the index.vue file.

You see it running here, so you can better understand: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/perfectimprints/precisionfirestopping.com.

Vue complains that the component is not defined, but is registered on render.

Comment: there're some errors in that component

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing to pass `boxes` props to your component:

```
    <Boxes :boxes="boxes" />
```

and inside the component you should add `props:['boxes']` like :

```
   <script>
      export default {
        name: "Boxes",
        props:['boxes'],
        data() {}
       }
    </script>
```

check this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/7k8y3n0ym0)

you could learn about `props` and how to pass data from parent to child component in these  [doc1](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and [doc2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Comment: That worked, thanks! Could you link me to some docs or explain why this works?

Comment: Perfect thank you, I will study up. Also, when I try and pass something like: `<b-button :href="link">Button</b-button> it gives me the error: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'link' in undefined`

Comment: in which component you're having that?

Comment: When I try and add to the `Boxes` component.

Comment: because you don't define a property called `link` in your script

Comment: I fixed it. Inserting my component on the page now looks like this: `<Boxes v-for="box in boxes" v-bind:key="box.title" :title="box.title" :text="box.text"  />` like it should. Thanks for all your help.